# Restore NewForm.aspx using form from another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I managed to ruin my NewForm.aspx while trying to add a new row to the form. I thought we had a backup of the original, but I can't find it so I think it may have been deleted.

I have copied a NewForm.aspx from another list, is it possible to adapt this to work with my other list?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1):

**is it possible to adapt this to work with my other list?**

No . I don't recommend you to do something like this because the copied `newform` has a reference to its original list .

So the best way to create a `newform` for your list is to,

- Open your list via Sharepoint Designer.
- At Forms Section > Click New button > Add new Form and set it as default .

[image]